# Get all the text between quotes matching one of the word

Tags: regex, ruby, string

```
a:5:{s:12:"SubmissionID";s:0:"";s:13:"NotesClientID";s:4:"1891";s:5:"Field";a:5:
{i:0;s:7:"8/19/19";i:1;s:0:"";i:4;s:0:"";i:5;s:160:"client is dismissed due to no contact with me or with his assigned Recovery
Coach";i:7;s:0:"";}s:10:"SecurityID";s:40:"a31b7ea7f9191465525d0ac9a6358ba7b3d3e0fc";s:13:"action_doSave";s:4:"Save";}
```

In above string expected output is "client is dismissed due to no contact with me or with his assigned Recovery Coach"

this contains **dismissed** word.

Similarly, regex should pick up string containing one of the dismissed/discharged/amenable in string.

I have tried this at https://rubular.com/r/QMFAHjUgaYdjpM

Comment: Please don't link to screenshots, if it is not necessary. Post your regex, which you want to discuss, as text. Also, I don't understand from your question, how the start of the substring you are interested in, is defined, since you have several quoted substrings in your string.

Comment: @user1934428, As I understand, the OP wishes to extract a string enclosed by double-quotes that contains any of three specified words and no double-quotes. Akash, is that correct? Whenever you give an example you should show the desired result. I suggest you edit to clarify.

Comment: @AkashK : Also clarify the effect, if more than one string matches the criterium. Do you want to get an array of all matching strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may match the desired text with the following regular expression.

```
/.*?"(?=(?:[^"]*\bdismissed\b[^"]*"))\K[^"]*(?=")/m
```

[Start your engine!](https://rubular.com/r/LSXLbvOgR8uTrN)

Detailed information about each element of the regex is given at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/GOgC2c/3/)<sup>1</sup>.

If the variable `str` holds the text given as an example in the question, one may write:

```
str.scan(/.*?"(?=(?:[^"]*\bdismissed\b[^"]*"))\K[^"]*(?=")/m)
  #=> ["client is dismissed due to no contact with me or with his assigned Recovery\nCoach"]
```

[String#scan] returns an array contains each match of the regex. Here there is a single match.

Ruby's regex engine performs the following operations.

```
/
.*?                : match 0+ characters, lazily
"                  : match a double-quote
(?=                : begin a positive lookahead to assert that
                     'dismissed' appears before the next double-quote
  (?:              : begin a non-capture group
    [^"]*          : match 0+ characters other than double-quotes
    \bdismissed\b  : match 'dismissed'
    [^"]*          : match 0+ characters other than double-quotes
    "              : match a double-quote
  )                : end non-capture group
)                  : end positive lookahead
\K                 : forget all matched so far and reset match
[^"]*              : match 0+ characters other than double-quotes
(?=")              : assert the next character is a double-quote
/m                 : multiline mode to match line terminators
```

---

Addendum: I missed the mention in the question that the target word could be any of "dismissed", "discharged" or "amenable". Rather than me revising my answer, suffice it to say that where

```
\bdismissed\b
```

appears in the regex that should be replaced with

```
\b(?:dismissed|discharged|amenable)\b
```

<sup>1. Move the cursor around for detailed explanations.</sup>

Comment: I think you need to add the possible other `dismissed/discharged/amenable` keywords.  I was thinking something like this: https://rubular.com/r/B4xaGhdbrR3k8p

Comment: @MDR, thanks for the head-up. I had a quick look at the link you gave, where you use a capture group. That seems to work fine, though I have an irrational preference for just matching, when possible. A tiny detail: you need not escape a double- (or single-) quote.